# Convert Strings that hold only an Number into INT

Tags: php, arrays

I got an `array` full of items, all are `string`. But many of the items should be `INT`.

**I got:**

```php
$myArray = [
    'id' => '123',
    'title' => 'Hello World',
    'count' => '333'
];
```

**I want:**

```php
$myArray = [
    'id' => 123,
    'title' => 'Hello World',
    'count' => 333
];
```

**I tried:**

```php
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    if($value == (int)$value) {
        $myArray[$key] = (int)$value;
    }
}
```

- **$value == (int)$value** is always true and kills my title
- **$value === (int)$value** is always false my id and count are still string
- **is_int($value)** is always false my id and count are still string

And the I run out of ideas :-/

I'm on PHP 7.1.19 (cli)

Comment: you can try `$value == strval((int)$value)`

Comment: use intval() instead ( returns the number on success, 0 on failure )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try i's_numeric' It will find whether a variable is a number or a numeric string
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: Be careful if using `is_numeric` and then casting to `(int)`--you might chop off some floats unintentionally.

Comment: I just got INT and STRING in my array so I choose this solution over regex. But @ggorlen is right, if you need more flexibility and want to protect float values, then his solution might be the best.

Answer (score 2):

//If you want just integer, use this

```js
$myArray = [
    'id' => '123',
    'title' => 'Hello World',
    'count' => '333'
];

foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    if(IsIntegerOnly($value)) {
        $myArray[$key] = (int)$value;
    }
}


function IsIntegerOnly($str)
{
  return (is_numeric($str) && $str >= 0 && $str == round($str));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Match the string by regular expression of int format:

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match('/^-?\d+$/', $value)) {
        $myArray[$key] = (int)$value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows...

```
array_walk(&$array,
    create_function('&$value', '$value = (int)$value;');
);
```

Comment: Not working: **array_walk(&$array** Call-time pass-by-reference was removed in PHP5.4, **create_function** is deprecated, the ";" in line two is wrong and most importent you simply just use **$value = (int)$value** on all elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match('/^-?[0-9.]+$/', $value)) {
        $myArray[$key] = (int)$value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking numeric and then casting to `int` can cause accidental truncation of floats. Here's an option to handle such cases with regex:

```
$myArray = [
    'id' => '123',
    'title' => 'Hello World',
    'count' => '333.7',
    'something' => '-55.6',
    'something else' => '-.26'
];

foreach ($myArray as $k => $v) {
    if (preg_match('`^-?\d+$`', $v)) {
        $myArray[$k] = (int)$v;
    }
    else if (preg_match('`^-?\d*\.\d+`', $v)) {
        $myArray[$k] = (double)$v;
    }
}

var_dump($myArray);
```

#### Output

```
array(5) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(123)
  ["title"]=>
  string(11) "Hello World"
  ["count"]=>
  float(333.7)
  ["something"]=>
  float(-55.6)
  ["something else"]=>
  float(-0.26)
}
```

Comment: Thx for the most flexible solution and protecting the floats.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```php
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'id' || $key =='count') {
        $myArray[$key] = (int)$value;
    }
}
```

Comment: $myArray was just an example, at the moment I got 2 arrays with 70-80 different items and don't want to map them all.